# OpenEdge 10.2A - prodict/load_df.p - Load New Objects Online, Ignoring Errors, Gives Warning

Tags: load, openedge, linux-disk-free

I'm trying to load new objects using load_df.p and I do NOT want to see any messages. But even if I give "*ignore any errors and commit the loading of the .df*" parameter as **yes** it gives a warning.

```
RUN prodict/load_df.p ("c:\temp\delta.df,yes,NEW OBJECTS").
```

It raises a warning message as follows:

**There have been errors encountered in the loading of this df and you have selected to commit the transaction anyway.**

**Are you sure you want to commit with missing information?**

How can I suppress this message and make load_df.p to continue loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract prodict.pl and customize load_df.p however you'd like.

Comment: I thougth there might be a parameter which I might set it. I think you are suggesting Instead of using prodict.pl, I should extract load_df.p code, and customize it. Makes sense :)

Comment: I don't remember by heart. But even if there is, extracting load_df.p and looking at it will answer all your questions, since you'll have the code it runs.